# Add to sources.list with a command? (not a redirect or text editor)

Tags: debian, apt-get

I'm using Debian stable (squeeze) and found this command `add-apt-repository` but it's not found when I try use it.

I'm sure I've used a command before which added a repo but I can't remember what it was.

Comment: The answers are correct, but even better would have been if they had mentioned `apt-file` to help you help yourself in the future. In this case, you should have run `apt-file search apt-add-repository` to find the package which contains the command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the command apt-add-repository in Debian as well as Ubuntu. That command, or rather executable, is as the previous poster mentioned, in the python-software-properties package.

If you want to use the command on Debian, simply install the python-software-properties package this way;

```
 $ sudo apt-get update
 $ sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
```

Then you'll be able to call the command this way;

```
$ add-apt-repository [OPTIONS] REPOSITORY
```

Comment: More on add-apt-repository at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/add-apt-repository:

To add you need to follow the below syntax in your terminal:

add-apt-repository 'deb uri distribution [component1] [component2] [...]'

add-apt-repository ppa:<ppa_name>

Examples:

add-apt-repository 'deb http://packages.linuxmint.com/ julia main'

add-apt-repository ppa:gnome-desktop

Comment: I just did this and add-apt-repository is still not there

Answer (score 1):

This command is contained in package python-software-properties.

Maybe you used this command in ubuntu (it's preinstalled in ubuntu karmic)?